# azure media service transcoding using custom preset

Tags: azure-webjobs, video-encoding, azure-media-services

I am using webjob in azure web service to process the encoding of the video and default preset doesn't fix the VVS (video rotating issue) and trim video option.

When I use the custom preset then it will fail and job state changes from 'scheduled' to 'processing' then to 'Error' instead of 'finished'.  I just can't figure it out.  It doesn't throw exception to know what the error is either

link to my preset in xml.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwaYuYfb7VCoSV9Ed0lOeUN5NDg/view

```
//MediaService.cs
var localPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_PATH");
var filePath = Path.Combine(localPath, "CustomPreset.xml");
string configuration = File.ReadAllText(filePath); 

var multibitrateTask = job.Tasks.AddNew("Custom Encoding Task", azureMediaEncoder, configuration, TaskOptions.None);
multibitrateTask.InputAssets.Add(mediaServiceAsset);
multibitrateTask.OutputAssets.AddNew($"Multibirate ouput for {mediaServiceAsset.Name}", AssetCreationOptions.None);

job = await job.SubmitAsync(); 

//function.cs
if (jobMessage.EventType == "JobStateChange")
{
 //try get old and new state
 if (jobMessage.Properties.Any(p => p.Key == "OldState") && jobMessage.Properties.Any(p => p.Key == "NewState"))
  {
    string oldJobState = jobMessage.Properties.First(p => p.Key == "OldState").Value.ToString();
    string newJobState = jobMessage.Properties.First(p => p.Key == "NewState").Value.ToString();

await log.WriteLineAsync(string.Format("job state has changed from {0} to {1}", oldJobState, newJobState));

string newState = jobMessage.Properties["NewState"].ToString();
     if (newState == "Finished") //<--fails here
     {
       string jobId = jobMessage.Properties["JobId"].ToString();
      var mediaServiceWrapper = new MediaServiceWrapper(_mediaServiceName, _mediaServiceKey, _azureStorageAccount);
      var result = await mediaServiceWrapper.PrepareAssetsForAdaptiveStreamingAsync(jobId); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the related code ? Is it working with a simple console app ? Only failed using webjob ? locally when deployed ?

Comment: Thanks your comment, I have not tried with the console app, I tried with the webjob on azure.  I had the default encoding working but not when I tried custom preset using xml or json.

Comment: I find a [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-check-job-progress/) that  talks about how to monitor job process. Please have a try to catch the job detail error message. Hope it can help to debug it.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thanks for that Tom.  I will give that a try.

Comment: Wil, let us know if you are still stuck here. We definitely could help if you give us a JobID and the data center where it is failing in. I can look up the error details for you if you can't trap it in the catch.  Also, have you tried submitting the same file and XML custom preset through the Azure Media Explorer tool and checking the Error message there?

Comment: @johndeu, oh great, thanks much for that I will try the explorer tool and suggestion by tom tonight and will update this post.

Comment: The job stopped due to cancellation or an error.
Job ID: nb:jid:UUID:056611ff-509a-49c3-b150-3b21ef4e2550
Job Name: Multibitrate generation for 2bb538fe-4ce4-4ddf-97c6-c80587adb029_404464e360f945ff89c19bf82d84509b_5ef4c722-9159-449b-b9e5-387dc2b58dde_false.MOV
Job State: Error
Job started (server UTC time): 11/2/2016 1:25:33 AM
 
Task Id: nb:tid:UUID:a3b07559-4b96-4d31-9b2e-2afbc25822d9
Error Code: TransientSystem
Error Message: A transient error has occurred. We apologize for the inconvenience. Please try again.

Comment: also tried the explorer tool but didn't work for me

Comment: what's the difference between Azure Media Encoder (AME) VS Media Encoder Standard (MES).  I am not sure which one I am using really.

Comment: Make sure to use MES - not the older AME... AME is the first encoder that we shipped, but have since deprecated - Don't use AME!

Comment: Ok. Looked at your job and here are some issues that I discovered.

1) you are using the Wrong Encoder. You are pointing to the old deprecated Azure Media Encoder (where did you get that from? Docs or old samples someplace we missed?If so, we need to clean up.)  You should always be using "Media Encoder Standard" v1.1 or greater (nb:mpid:UUID:ff4df607-d419-42f0-bc17-a481b1331e56)


2) Your input job asset name is really, really long... any chance you can shorten that up? Could be contributing here. That's a LOT of GUIDs in the filename.

Comment: assetName="Multibirate ouput for 2bb538fe-4ce4-4ddf-97c6-c80587adb029_404464e360f945ff89c19bf82d84509b_5ef4c722-9159-449b-b9e5-387dc2b58dde_false.MOV"

3) Your Preset XML custom file is for "Media Encoder Standard", but you are submitting the job to the old "Azure Media Encoder" which had a different XML schema.  That would cause the job to fail. 

In the backend I'm seeing a System.NullReferenceException when applying the preset.  So it appears to be #3 is the primary issue.

Comment: Ah, ok, I will fix that tonight and see.  I am using those guids for different reasons but if that cause an error then I will change it but for now I will just change the encoder and see.  Thank you very much @johndeu.

Comment: Cool. Mark as answered if you are good to go now. :-)

Comment: @johndeu well, custom part still doesn't work so I try again tonight.  Thanks.

Comment: @johndeu Finally got it working, somehow I had to create two jobs; one with video and another one for thumbnail.  I am not sure why since I added thumbnail on xml preset.  Anyway, it works now.  Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I was using Azure Media Encoder (AME) and now I changed to Media Encoder Standard (MES)

IMediaProcessor processor = GetLatestMediaProcessorByName("Media Encoder Standard");